# Why does notify not want to work in my defered example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

I'm just starting to learn about jquery deferred. Things are going pretty well till I got to the notify area. You will see a section of my code commented out where I thought I could use notify but no go.

```
var obj = {};

$('div').each(function(i){
  $(this).fadeIn().fadeOut(1000 * (i + 1),function(){
    console.log(i + " has fade out");
  });
  // I thought this would work but .notify is not a function?
  $('div').notify(i);
});

$('p').each(function(i){
  $(this).fadeIn().fadeOut(1000 * (i + 1),function(){
    console.log(i + " has fade out");
  });
});

$('div').promise(obj).done(function(){
  console.log("done");
}).progress(function(value){
  console.log(value);
});

obj.done(function(){
  console.log("obj done method called");
});

obj.fail(function(err){
  console.log(err);
});

obj.always(function(){
  console.log("obj always method called");
});

$('div').promise().then(
  function(result){
    console.log(result);

    result.each(function(){
      $(this).fadeIn()
    });

    //$(result[0]).fadeIn();
  },
  function(error){ },
  function(value){ }
);

$.when($('div'),$('p')).done(function(a,b){
  console.log("all done with both");
});
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work. What do you mean? You get an error or it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: `.notify()` is a method of a `Deferred` object. `$('div')` returns a `jQuery` object, not a `Deferred` object.

Comment: also it seems like notify got removed in JQuery versions 3.X

Answer (score 0):

The `.notify()` method can only be applied to a `Deferred` object. `$('div')` returns a jQuery collection, not a deferred object. You use `.promise()` to get a `Deferred` object that resolves when all the animations of the selected elements have completed. Also, inside your `.each()` loop you should just call `.notify()` on the current element, not all `div` elements.

So it should be:

```
$(this).promise().notify(i);
```

Comment: `$(this).promise().notify(i);` won't work either because `.notify()`, like `.resolve()` and `.reject(), is a Deferred method, not a Promise method.

Comment: I thought they were the same thing, now I see that `Promise` is a subset of of `Deferred`. You can get a Promise from Deferred, but not the other way around.